# Firestore Error: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Invalid argument (dartObject): Could not convert: Instance of '_FieldValueServerTimestamp'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using `flutter` and `firestore` and what I want to do is adding an object as a child inside a list, each time I hit a submit button. Inside that object, I want to have a `createdAt` field, where the timestamp information should be stored. For that, i'm trying to use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, but i'm getting the following error.

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: [cloud_firestore/unknown] Invalid argument (dartObject): Could not convert: Instance of '_FieldValueServerTimestamp'`

The code is as below:

```
reference.update({
  'parentData': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
    {
      'data': myData,
      'createdAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }
  ]),
});
```

I'm also importing the library:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

Comment: Hello, investigating the error message lead me to this [link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2153#issuecomment-601484646), it seems that this was a known issue, I would suggest to try to update your dependencies and try again.